# Python: Listen for keys only when application is in focus

Tags: python, keyboard, keylistener, pynput

I have a small project on doing a audio-player for the console window. It's all going great, but I'm struggling with one small detail. I want when the user presses a key, space for example, to pause the audio, and I've achieved that. The problem is: the audio is pausing even when the player is not on focus.

For an example, I put some music on the player, and go the web browser. If space is pressed while navigating in the browser, the audio will stop.

I want the program to listen ONLY when the app is focused. Here is a part of my code:

```py
def play_pause():
    global buttons
    
    if '⏸' in buttons:
        buttons = (' ' * 21) + '⏮  ⯈  ⏭'
    else:
        buttons = (' ' * 21) + '⏮  ⏸  ⏭'
    
    audio.play_pause_audio()

def controller(key):
    if key == Key.space or key == Key.media_play_pause:
        play_pause()

    # TO DO:
    # if key == Key.left or key == Key.media_previous:
    #     pass
    # if key == Key.right or key == Key.media_next:
    #     pass

    draw_player()

def start_player(audio_name):
    global current_audio
    current_audio = audio_name

    draw_player()

    with Listener(on_press=controller) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I'm currently using pynput: `from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener`.

Comment: Are you using windows now?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA No, I'm on Linux. ArcoLinux to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of digging, and I have found the perfect solution. `Pygetwindow` is probably the way to go. I'm pretty sure it works on other operating systems than Windows, and it allows you to see what application is in focus.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
import pygetwindow as pgw

def get_application_in_focus():
    return pgw.getActiveWindow()

print(get_application_in_focus())
```

This prints a long string, that includes several things you probably don't need (like the size of the application, and where the application is on the screen). This is what the program above printed for me:

`<Win32Window left="754", top="62", width="711", height="721", title="*IDLE Shell 3.12.1*">`

As you can see, there is a lot of information that is unnecessary here. The important part is the "title" section of the string. It shows what app is running in focus, in my case, the IDLE shell.

So all you have to do is check if the app name is in the string, and get the app name simply by running the application with the audio player open (using some time sleeping functions to allow python to wait for you to open the audio player). Here's an example of it being implemented:

```
if "app name" in gw.getActiveWindow():
    #do stuff
```

I don't know if this works for ArcoLinux, but I guess there is kind of only one way to figure out :).